# Filter and manipulate the get_current_user() function

Tags: filters, users

**What i need:** To perform my own logic every time `get_current_user` is being called

Is it possible to use `add_filter()` to intervene in the `get_current_user` function logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm seeing in the github repo.
`get_current_user` doesn't exist.
What you do have is `wp_get_current_user`, this function does this

```php
return _wp_get_current_user();
```

So now I checked what `_wp_get_current_user` does.
It checks a global variable `$global_user`, if it's not empty, return an instance of it (didn't find any actions for that).
If empty it does a few checks and runs `wp_set_current_user()`, this function has one action

```php
/**
 * Fires after the current user is set.
 *
 * @since 2.0.1
 */
do_action( 'set_current_user' );
```

So you can hook into it and use `global $current_user;`

`_wp_get_current_user` also has a filter, also at the end of the function block.

```php
/**
 * Filters the current user.
 *
 * The default filters use this to determine the current user from the
 * request's cookies, if available.
 *
 * Returning a value of false will effectively short-circuit setting
 * the current user.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @param int|false $user_id User ID if one has been determined, false otherwise.
 */
$user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
```

I'm not sure how much help any of those events are but worth a shot.